# Setting Text Size in Android Applications

Tags: android, textview

Im using Eclipse to write an android app and using the latest API to compile.

I am setting the TextSize of multiple TextView controls.  Some of the controls were defined in  XML, while some of the TextView controls were created dynamically in code.  When I look at TextView controls in the application the text sizes are different.  I'm setting the text sizes using the same dimension, so I don't understand why it's coming out differently.

Here's the dimension I have defined:

```
<!--  Default Font Size -->
<dimen name="font_size">12sp</dimen>
```

Here is where I am setting one of the textview controls in XML:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/lblSection1Title"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/device_info_title"
android:textColor="@color/FontColor"
android:textSize="@dimen/font_size" />
```

And here is where I am setting the text size in code:

```
m_fTextSize = getResources().getDimension( R.dimen.font_size );
txtLabel = new TextView(this.m_xContext);
xLayoutParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams( 0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.35f );
xLayoutParams.setMargins((int)m_fMarginLeft,  (int)m_fMarginTop,  (int)m_fMarginRight,  (int)m_fMarginBottom);
txtLabel.setLayoutParams(xLayoutParams);
txtLabel.setTextColor(this.m_iTextColor);
txtLabel.setTextSize(this.m_fTextSize);
```

If you look at the screen shot you can see that the TextView controls that were created dynamically are smaller than the rest of the TextViews on the screen that were defined in the XML.

Here's an link to the screen shot: 
http://emildiego.com/systemprofiler/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2013/04/screen-shot-text-copy.png

I know that calling getDimension adjusts the text size based on the screen density, but wouldn't setting the TextSize in the XML do the same thing?

Thanks in advance for the assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer can be found here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDimension(int)

When Android returns the value for `getDimension()` it is already adjusting for screen density.  Try using `getDimensionPixelSize()` instead.

Comment: I realize that getDimension adjusts the size based on the screen density.  But why doesn't using the dimension font_size in the XML do the same thing?  Why am I getting 2 different font sizes using the same dimension?

Comment: getDimensionPixelSize() still returns a font size that is different than TextViews that are set using XML.  So i'm still getting TextViews that have different font size using the same dimension.